# How many subsets of $[0,1)$ are there modulo null sets?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

For subsets $A$ and $B$ of $[0,1)$, say $A\sim B$ iff $\lambda(A\Delta B)=0$ where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure.

**Question:** How many equivalence classes of subsets of $[0,1)$ are there given AC?

I would guess the answer is $2^c$ given AC, but I haven't got a proof.

What got me thinking about this was trying to find a way to say that there are more nonmeasurable sets than measurable ones. There are, of course, $2^c$ of each, but modulo null sets there are only $c$ measurable ones (at least given AC), so if there were more than $c$ subsets modulo null sets, we could say that modulo null sets there are more nonmeasurable sets than measurable ones.

Comment: I don't think that this is *really* a question about the axiom of choice. I mean, if this is a question about the axiom of choice, we need to start tagging many other questions like that as well.

Comment: Agreed, though there are questions about what values for the cardinality are options without AC. (E.g., if all sets are measurable then we get $\le c^2$, assuming that the proof that there are $c$ Borel sets goes through without AC.)

Comment: Luckily $\mathfrak c^2=\mathfrak c$ without using choice. Unluckily, the assumption that there are $\frak c$ Borel sets does use the axiom of choice.

Comment: Does it use anything beyond countable choice?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Actually it seems to. The Consequences of AC page says that 8 (Countable Choice) is true and 363 ($2^c$ Borel sets) is false in $\cal M5(\aleph)$ and $\cal M38$.

Comment: Well. I don't know which models these are, but I'll investigate further when I return home. Thanks giving me something for tonight. I'll get back to you with some further conclusions tomorrow.

Comment: I don't get this discussion. Isn't this space a basic example of a complete, separable metric space without isolated points?
If so, why isn't it obvious that its cardinality is equal to the continuum?

Comment: This is an elegant argument if you restrict to measurable $A,B$, but the OP considers arbitrary sets.

Comment: @Alexander: I look up which models are these two, and those are the models were every set is Lebesgue measurable (Solovay's classic model, and Shelah's model separating the perfect set and Baire properties from Lebesgue measurability). I don't know the argument, but I'll see if I can find somewhere that it is written. I doubt the Consequences dictionary would have added that without reason. That's new to me, so thanks!

Comment: @Asaf: It's a bit strange to me, too. I would have expected countable or dependent choice would be all that's needed to prove that there are $c$ Borel sets (and thanks for the catch that $c^2=c$). Maybe we should just try to write out one of the standard proofs very carefully. (No time right now for me.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, there are $2^\mathfrak{c}$ equivalence classes.  In fact, I claim that there is a collection $S$ of $\mathfrak{c}$ disjoint non-null subsets of $[0,1)$; taking all unions of subcollections of $S$ gives $2^\mathfrak{c}$ inequivalent subsets of $[0,1)$.

To construct this $S$, let $N$ be the set of all null Borel sets and enumerate $N\times\mathfrak{c}$ with order type $\mathfrak{c}$.  Using this enumeration, define a function $f:[0,1)\to\mathfrak{c}$ by induction such that for each $(n,\alpha)\in N\times\mathfrak{c}$, $f^{-1}(\{\alpha\})\not\subseteq n$.  We can do this because at each stage of the induction, we have defined $f$ at fewer than $\mathfrak{c}$ points, and the complement of $n$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.  The collection $S=\{f^{-1}(\{\alpha\})\}_{\alpha\in\mathfrak{c}}$ then consists of $\mathfrak{c}$ disjoint non-null sets.

---

Here is an earlier version of my answer, which is a slight variant on a standard argument that nonmeasurable sets exist and shows there must be more than $\mathfrak{c}$ equivalence classes, but does not show there must be $2^\mathfrak{c}$ of them.  Let $S$ be any collection of $\mathfrak{c}$ subsets of $[0,1)$; we will find a subset $A\subseteq[0,1)$ that is not equivalent to any element of $S$.  Let $N$ be the set of all Borel null sets and enumerate $N\times S$ with order type $\mathfrak{c}$.  Define the characteristic function of $A$ inductively such that for each $(n,B)\in N\times S$, $A\Delta B\not\subseteq n$; we can do this because at each stage of the induction we have defined the characteristic function at fewer than $\mathfrak{c}$ points and the complement of $n$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: But does "more than $c$" imply "$2^c$"?

Comment: Thanks! The existence of a set $S$ with the requisite properties (well, or the equivalent claim on the square) also follows from Sierpinski's 1938 partition of the square into perfect sets such that any choice of one element of each of the perfect sets gives a set with full outer measure: https://eudml.org/doc/213031

Answer (score 8):

**Edit.** I had posted this answer to complement Eric's original answer, which showed that the number of classes was at least ${\frak c}^+$, since at that time we didn't quite yet know whether there were $2^{\frak c}$ classes. Afterwards, however, Eric improved his answer to get $2^{\frak c}$ directly. Following the comments, though, I have left this answer up.

---

Let me complement Eric's answer by showing that it is relatively
consistent to have strictly more than ${\frak c}^+$ many
equivalence classes. Indeed, it is relatively consistent with ZFC
to have $2^{\frak c}$ many equivalence class, in a case where this is
larger than ${\frak c}^+$.

Specifically, I claim that if the continuum hypothesis holds and
there is a thick Kurepa tree (an $\omega_1$ tree with
$2^{\omega_1}$ many branches), then there are
$2^{\omega_1}=2^{\frak c}$ many equivalence classes. Indeed, I shall construct an almost-disjoint family of $2^{\omega_1}$ many Vitali sets.

To see this, let $T$ be a thick Kurepa tree, and let $\langle
A_\alpha\mid\alpha<\omega_1\rangle$ enumerate the equivalence
classes of reals under translation-by-a-rational. Label the
$\alpha^{th}$ level of $T$ with the countably many elements of
$A_\alpha$. For any path $s$ through $T$, the set $A_s$ of labels
appearing on the nodes of $s$ will be a Vitali set, and therefore
non-measurable. Further, any two distinct paths $s\neq t$ will
have $A_s\cap A_t$ being countable, and so $A_s\not\sim A_t$.
Since $T$ is a thick Kurepa tree, we therefore have $2^{\omega_1}$
many branches and thus this many equivalence classes modulo your
relation. The collection $\{\ A_s\mid s\in[T]\ \}$ is an almost-disjoint family of $2^{\omega_1}$ many Vitali sets.

Finally, let me explain that it is relatively consistent from an
inaccessible cardinal that there is a thick Kurepa tree, yet CH
holds and $2^{\omega_1}$ is very large. One way to do this is as
follows. Start with $\kappa$ inaccessible in $V$ and $2^\kappa$
very large (by forcing if necessary). Let $V[G]$ be the forcing
extension by the Levy collapse, so that $\kappa=\omega_1^{V[G]}$.
Consider the tree $T=(2^{<\kappa})^V$ in the model $V[G]$. Since
every ordinal less than $\kappa$ was made countable, this has
become an $\omega_1$-tree. Yet, since $2^\kappa$ was very large
and cardinals $\kappa$ and above were preserved, we have
$(2^\kappa)^V$ many branches through this tree. So it is thick.

Comment: Ah, Eric has now improved his answer to give $2^{\frak c}$ directly. So that subsumes the need for this argument.

Comment: Vote up this comment if I should delete.

Comment: Vote up this comment if you (as I) think that JDH should NOT delete his answer.

Comment: You might just edit the first paragraph to clarify that it doesn't extend Eric's (current) result.

Comment: @NateEldredge Good idea; I have edited.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek : More like a way to redeem oneself for whatever sin you think you have commited, mostly related to (sneaky) reputation gain.

Comment: I think I'll forego the self-flagellation, since I wasn't taking myself to have sinned. My only concern had been that Eric's result was stronger. But I do now find it interesting to have an almost disjoint family of Vitali sets, since it isn't clear to me how to construct such a family directly, and so I shall let that be the contribution of this answer.

Comment: Meanwhile, I've asked a question about the issue mentioned in my previous comment. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/200537/for-a-partition-of-mathbbr-into-countably-infinite-sets-must-there-be-an-a.